# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR in Chrome but not Edge

Tags: google-chrome

I temporarily changed the DNS pointer to a website and then changed it back.
Since doing this the link no longer works in Chrome on my computer.
It does work on another computer at this location.
The link also works in Edge on my computer.

I have tried clearing the browsing history in Chrome.
I have also tried [chrome://net-internals/#dns  and ipconfig /flushdns](https://superuser.com/questions/1077503/chrome-err-ssl-protocol-error-on-known-working-site)

Answer (score 0):

I wound up uninstalling Chrome and then reinstalling it.