# One (only one) of my users cant access my website due to ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: networking, ssl

I have a website running on Google's infrastructure (the URL ends in appspot.com). There are a number of users using it without any trouble, but one of them is not being able to reach it. In the developer console, you can see that the connections to the site throw ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR errors.

The computer is a Windows box and it happens with several browsers, not only with her main one (Chrome).

I asked her to reboot her router and it started working well for 5 minutes, but after that, it started to fail again.

Another test we did was to reboot the router and turn off the Windows firewall and it worked fine until we turned it on again.

I am not able to find any firewall rule preventing it from working. How could I troubleshoot this?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome ERR\_SSL\_PROTOCOL\_ERROR on known working site](https://superuser.com/questions/1077503/chrome-err-ssl-protocol-error-on-known-working-site)

Comment: I will try that, thank you!