# Only able to use wifi over VPN

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn

I'm using Proton VPN. Recently i started having issues with my wifi - I can only browse websites when on VPN. Once the VPN is turned off, I am able to ping hosts without issues but my browser won't load any sites. The connection also shows as having no internet access.

This happens both on my laptop and my phone so I suspect it's an issue with the router? I don't recall making any changes recently and I've tried rebooting the router but that didn't help. My router is TP Link Archer C6.

I disabled the "kill switch", so the issue is not my VPN blocking non-VPN connections.

I only started having this problem recently, previously I has having no issues and could use the internet both with the VPN on and off.

When i try to open any website on my laptop, the page returns this error: `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG`.

Let me know if i can provide any more details to help troubleshoot this.

Comment: If you remove the vpn client does the problem still exhibit itself? Does [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1077503/chrome-err-ssl-protocol-error-on-known-working-site) answer your question?

Comment: @Ramhound removing the VPN client doesn't solve the issue. flushing the dns cache also didn't help.